# Any recommended exercise book for undergraduate finite group representation theory and modules theory?

Tags: reference-request, modules, representation-theory, book-recommendation

I would like to take a course on undergraduate finite group representation theory and modules theory, so I am looking for some problem books with solutions which are about the level of "Michael Artin - Algebra" Chapter 10 and 14 (Textbook of the course). Or any books with lots of examples would do just fine. Could anyone give me some recommendations please?

Answer (score 2):

I have James and Liebeck 'Representations and Characters of Groups', and I've found it pretty good!

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems quite nice.